# How to insert Image in my Canvas?

Tags: .net, wpf, image, canvas

I want to add an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982) in `MyCanvas`:

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    private VisualCollection children;

    public MyCanvas()
    { this.children = new VisualCollection(this); }


    public void AddVisual(Visual visual)
    { this.children.Add(visual); }

    public void RemoveVisual(Visual visual)
    { this.children.Remove(visual); }

    public void ClearVisuals()
    { this.children.Clear(); }


    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        { return this.children.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    { return this.children[index]; }
}
```

I tried:

```
my_canvas.Children.Add(my_image);
// or also
my_canvas.AddVisual(my_image);
```

But `my_image` does not appear. What is the problem and how i have to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not rendered because I have overridden GetVisualChild and I return only my own visuals. Any visuals generated by children of the Canvas are simply ignored.

Since I'm still working directly with visuals I probably should use a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) object and an [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) instead of an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982). In the DrawingVisual I can simply render the ImageSource with [DrawingContext.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606804.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Your child probably lacks some crucial property values, like does it have non-zero width and height?

You may want to create a sample form in the designer, see what properties it sets, and do the same in your code.

Comment: When i add my_image as children of a "classic" Canvas, everything is working properly.

Comment: Then it's probably your custom canvas, which doesn't have all required property values set to reasonable values.

Comment: exactly, but what are these properties? and what are reasonable values?

Comment: You should be able to determine that by looking at the XAML for the working form (the classic canvas you talk about above).

Comment: The XAML of the classic Canvas with inside an Image? And how i should be able to determine what i need in this way?

Comment: If you look at the XAML for the working form, there must be some canvas setting that you don't set when using your custom canvas.

Comment: No, you're wrong. This is the classic Canvas XAML: `<Canvas x:Name="my_canvas"/>`. And this is MyCanvas XAML: `<local:MyCanvas x:Name="my_canvas"/>`. There are not differences. But, have you test something?